# Using jQuery to see if a drop down menu select has changed

Tags: jquery

I would like to see if a particular drop down menu item has been selected or deselected.

I have tried

```
jQuery("#dropdownID option[value='selectionKey']").change(function() {
    if (jQuery("#dropdownID option[value='selectionKey']").attr('selected', 'selected'))
        DoSomething();
    else DoSomethingElse();
});
```

and

```
jQuery("#dropdownID").change(function() {
    if (jQuery("#dropdownID option[value='selectionKey']").attr('selected', 'selected'))
        DoSomething();
    else DoSomethingElse();
});
```

but neither block is triggered by changing the selection in the drop down menu.  That is, it never gets to the if statement.

Comment: You can't set an event on an `<option>` tag, only on the `<select>` tag.

Comment: `$('#dropdownID :selected').val()` will give you the selected value

Comment: @DotNetDreamer: I think you mean `$('#dropdownID').val()` :-)

Comment: Also, `.attr('selected', 'selected')` will *SET* the `selected` attribute, and return the jQuery object.

Comment: My problem is that changing the selection does not appear to trigger jQuery("#dropdownID").change(function() {.  I have a break point inside the block with Firebug and the script never breaks there.  I have looked at detecting any selected dropdown value with jquery and their solution is not working for me. Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Are you trying to bind the event handler before the element exist? Please read http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ to learn how to set up jQuery properly.

Comment: @Felix.  Yes.  That was my problem.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try something like this in jquery versions less than 1.7:

```
$("#dropdownID").live('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'selectionKey'){
        DoSomething();
    } else {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
});
```

You can try something like this in jquery versions greater than 1.7:

```
$("#dropdownID").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'selectionKey'){
        DoSomething();
    } else {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your two code blocks are *NOT* equivalent.  You can't just change `.live` to `.on` and expect it to work the same way.  `.on` has a different syntax if you want it to affect dynamic elements.  If you didn't want to affect dynamic elements, then why were you using `.live`?

Answer (score 3):

Try these:

```
jQuery("#dropdownID").change(function() {
    if (jQuery("#dropdownID option[value=selectionKey]").attr('selected', 'selected')) {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else {
DoSomethingElse();
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

or even less code:

```
<select id="dropdown1">
 <option value="1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

$(function() { //<------- stands for $(document).ready..
  $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWZbC/)

```
<select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
jQuery("#dropdownID").change(function() {
    if (jQuery("#dropdownID option[value='selectionKey']").is(':selected'))
        DoSomething();
    else DoSomethingElse();
});
```

But your second method should work if you compare them :

```
jQuery("#dropdownID").change(function() {
    if (jQuery("#dropdownID option[value='selectionKey']").attr('selected') == 'selected')
        DoSomething();
    else DoSomethingElse();
});
```

But it is alway better to use `.prop()`,  it will return a boolean :

```
jQuery("#dropdownID").change(function() {
    if (jQuery("#dropdownID option[value='selectionKey']").prop('selected')
        DoSomething();
    else DoSomethingElse();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the event to the `<select>`, not to the `<option>`.  Also you should just simply check if the value is what you want.

```
jQuery("#dropdownID").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'selectionKey'){
        DoSomething();
    }
    else{
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
});
```